# Unable to setup Android SDK on macOS Catalina?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

While installing Android studio, I got no path for Android sdk says "android sdk is missing" and it pointed to default path /Users/{username}/Library..

When I go physically to the location, cannot locate sdk.

It's my corp device and I cannot setup android studio.

Tried downloading command line tools from below:
https://developer.android.com/studio?pkg=tools

but not sure how sdk folder looks like. Need guidance

NOTE: I have ksh (.kshrc) file on my device.

Answer (score 3):

If You are looking for installing only android SDK. You can follow any of the methods below.

1. Install the Android studio (Manually)

> download without android SDK Android Studio bundled zip folder and install the same from here - https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads
> [image: android studio manual download]

2. User Homebrew and install android sdk - Easiest and preferred option!!!

> you can use Homebrew to install the Android SDK.

1. Install Homebrew from here (just follow the commands via MAC Terminal) - https://brew.sh/
2. Once you have installed HomeBrew run the following commands:
   More details here - https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/android-sdk#default

```
    brew tap homebrew/cask
    brew install --cask android-sdk
```

This will install the Android SDK tools in

```
/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/<version number>
```

Use this path to update your SDK path in android studio as shown in the post above. Hope this helps.

Comment: after running the command for installing android-sdk, 
`android-sdk has been officially discontinued upstream.
It may stop working correctly (or at all) in recent versions of macOS.` is printed

Comment: @ŽeljkoŠević I would recommend to install android sdk using android developer website using step 1.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> Project Structure and check the Android SDK Location:

[image]

Then Android Studio -> Preferences -> System Settings -> Android SDK (just type sdk in the search bar).
Download SDK Platforms and SDK Tools:

[image]

Comment: I'm getting only android version 10 other version is not visible in my list of Andriod sdk